# Use Loguru logging library to log requests made in an imported file

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-requests, loguru

So I have program written in a python file (main.py) that uses classes in an api wrapper file (bluerev.py). I want to use the loguru logger in main.py to collect all exceptions from the program + all requests made in the api wrapper. So the logging set up in the bluerev.py api wrapper looks like this:

```
import logging

#Logging setup
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())

class BluerevApiRequestHandler:

def __init__(self):
    self.date_str_format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"

@staticmethod
def setup_logger_for_requests():
    """
    Sets up the requests library to log api requests
    """
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
    requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    requests_log.propagate = True
```

THe main.py logging code looks like this:

```
from blurev import *
from loguru import logger
#more imports and code

@logger.catch
def main():
    # associated file and credential locations
    gmail_creds_file = "gmail_creds.json"
    revu_creds_file = r"revu_credentials.json"
    token_file = r"revu_refresh_token.json"
    files_location = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "rev_dist_files")
    review_files_location = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "files_to_distribute")

    # Set up Logging
    logging_file = r"plan_review_distributor.log"
    #logging_format_str = "%(levelname)s - %(asctime)-15s - %(filename)s - line %(lineno)d --> %(message)s"
    logger.add(os.path.join(files_location, logging_file),  level="WARNING")
    logger.add(os.path.join(files_location, logging_file), filter="blurev", level="DEBUG")

    #call the requests logging function here in main()
   request_handler = BluerevApiRequestHandler()
   request_handler.setup_logger_for_requests()

   #more code
```

So I am wondering how this should be changed so that requests being called in the blurev.py file by functions and code in main.py are being logged into the logging_file. Right now they are not.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, the `logger` is not defined in your `bluerev.py` example, si I can't tell how it is supposed to work.

Comment: Oops I had forgot the logger setup for blurev.py Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `loguru` uses a completely different mechanism for logging than the classic `logging` library. The classic `logging` library constructs a hierarchy of loggers, and log records are propagate up to the root (see the [Advanced logging tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial) from the Python docs for reference). But `loguru` does not use at all this hierarchy, it operates in a totally disjointed way from it.
So if you want the logs emitted using the classic `logging` library to be ultimately handled by `loguru`, you have to intercept them.

Here is a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of my solution :

```py
# main.py

import logging as classic_logging
import os

from blurev import BluerevApiRequestHandler
from loguru import logger as loguru_logger


@loguru_logger.catch
def main():
    logging_file = r"plan_review_distributor.log"
    loguru_logger.add(os.path.join(".", logging_file), filter=lambda rec: rec["name"] != "blurev", level="WARNING")
    loguru_logger.add(os.path.join(".", logging_file), filter="blurev", level="DEBUG")

    root_logger = classic_logging.getLogger("")
    root_logger.handlers = [InterceptHandler()]  # replace ANY pre-existing handler
    root_logger.setLevel("DEBUG")

    request_handler = BluerevApiRequestHandler()
    request_handler.do_something_using_requests()


########################################################################################################################
# recipe from https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#entirely-compatible-with-standard-logging
class InterceptHandler(classic_logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        # Get corresponding Loguru level if it exists
        try:
            level = loguru_logger.level(record.levelname).name
        except ValueError:
            level = record.levelno

        # Find caller from where originated the logged message
        frame, depth = classic_logging.currentframe(), 2
        while frame.f_code.co_filename == classic_logging.__file__:
            frame = frame.f_back
            depth += 1

        loguru_logger.opt(depth=depth, exception=record.exc_info).log(level, record.getMessage())
########################################################################################################################


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```py
# bluerev.py

import logging as classic_logging

import requests

bluerev_logger = classic_logging.getLogger(__name__)


class BluerevApiRequestHandler:

    def do_something_using_requests(self):
        print(requests.get("http://example.com").text.splitlines()[3])  # expecting: "    <title>Example Domain</title>"
        classic_logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3").warning("warning from requests")  # simulating
        bluerev_logger.debug("debug from bluerev")
        bluerev_logger.critical("critical from bluerev")
```

The idea is to add an handler to the classic root logger, which will transmit the log records to the loguru logger. We don't need to `setup_logger_for_requests`, we just let the log record propagate naturally from `"requests.packages.urllib3"` up the hierarchy.
I added a filter to the first `loguru` **sink** so that a `"blurev"` log record does not get written twice to the file (because caught by the two sinks).

This is the output I get :

```
# stdout

2022-01-07 11:58:02.480 | DEBUG    | urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn:227 - Starting new HTTP connection (1): example.com:80
2022-01-07 11:58:02.653 | DEBUG    | urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request:452 - http://example.com:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 648
2022-01-07 11:58:02.654 | WARNING  | blurev:do_something_using_requests:14 - warning from requests
2022-01-07 11:58:02.654 | DEBUG    | blurev:do_something_using_requests:15 - debug from bluerev
2022-01-07 11:58:02.654 | CRITICAL | blurev:do_something_using_requests:16 - critical from bluerev
    <title>Example Domain</title>
```

```
# plan_review_distributor.log

2022-01-07 11:58:02.654 | WARNING  | blurev:do_something_using_requests:14 - warning from requests
2022-01-07 11:58:02.654 | DEBUG    | blurev:do_something_using_requests:15 - debug from bluerev
2022-01-07 11:58:02.654 | CRITICAL | blurev:do_something_using_requests:16 - critical from bluerev
```

See [Loguru's documentation section "Entirely compatible with standard logging"](https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#entirely-compatible-with-standard-logging).
Also, you sometimes wrote "bluerev", some other times "bluerev", better watch out !